# Como acessar parâmetros recebidos de uma classe numa função externa javascript?

Tags: javascript, funções, classes

Como consigo acessar parâmetros recebidos de uma classe fora do escopo dela, como na função abaixo. Ou há outra forma melhor de fazer isso?

helper.js

```
class Helper {

    constructor(user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

rebeceUser function () {
 // recebe user
}
```

game.js

```
new Helper("João");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque parâmetros de entrada como argumento da função, por exemplo:

```
class Helper {

    constructor(user) {
         this.user = user;
     }
 }

rebeceUser function (variavelQualquer) {
    console.log(variavelQualquer);
 // recebe user
}
```

Quando você chamar o método da classe, apenas coloque uma variavel ou constante como parâmetro entre os parenteses do método

```
user = "João"
helper = new Helper(user);
helper.recebeUser(user);
```

Mas analisando o nome do método, creio que você queira dar "boas vindas" ao user da classe helper, para isso você não precisa de um parâmetro na função, mas apenas chamar o atributo que recebeu valor no construtor, ficaria assim:

```
class Helper {

    constructor(user) {
         this.user = user;
     }
 }

rebeceUser function () {
    console.log("Bem Vindo " + this.user);
}
```

-

```
user = "João"
helper = new Helper(user);
helper.recebeUser();
//Será impresso no console "Bem Vindo João"
```

(ah, e se estiverem em arquivos diferentes, terá de referenciar um ao outro, nesse caso o helper.js dentro do game.js)

Comment: Retorna "Bem Vindo undefined", como é em arquivos diferentes, estou referenciando o helper no game. Ainda assim não funciona.

Comment: Se você consegue acessar o metodo da classe dentro de game.js, então uma instancia da classe está lá dentro, como está instanciando a classe?

Comment: class Helper {

    constructor(user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}

function rebeceUser() {
    console.log("Bem Vindo " + this.user);
}

module.exports = Helper;
game.js:
let helper = require('./helper');
new helper("João");

Comment: Lembre que new retorna a referencia, se não estiver atribuindo new a lugar nenhum, a referencia fica vazia, e o objeto com o user usado no construtor se perde

Comment: dai eu passo para a função o retorno?

Comment: Você passa a referencia do objeto para uma variavel, e acessa os metodos da classe atraves dessa variavel: "let variavel = new Helper("João") ", --  " variavel.recebeUser() "

Answer (score 0):

Espero que eu tenha entendido sua pergunta. Lá vai:

Após instanciar a classe Helper, é só utilizar `.user` para acessar a propriedade.

```javascript
class Helper {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
}

var helper = new Helper('João');
console.log(helper.user); // João
```

Caso queira a função:

```
class Helper {
  constructor(user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
}

function recebeUser(objetoHelper) {
  return objetoHelper.user;
}

var helper = new Helper('Maria');
console.log( recebeUser(helper) ); // Maria
```